# Error: unexpected format for ID (), expected EVENTBUSNAME/RULENAME or RULENAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to deploy some event rules using Terraform. From what I've seen in the docs, my (JSON) format is fine. I can't figure out why it's throwing that error.

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "kinesis_stream" {
  name        = var.delivery_stream_name
  destination = "s3"

  s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = aws_iam_role.kinesis_data_firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.arn
  }
}


resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "successful_sign_in_rule" {
  description    = "Auth0 User Successfully signed in"
  event_bus_name = aws_cloudwatch_event_bus.event_bridge_event_bus.arn
  event_pattern  = <<EOF
  {
    "detail-type": [
      "s"
    ]
  }
EOF
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "successful_sign_in_rule_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.successful_sign_in_rule.name
  arn       = aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_stream.arn
}
```

Comment: It should be a name it seems, not an ARN, so you need `aws_cloudwatch_event_bus.event_bridge_event_bus.name`.

Comment: yeah name seems like a more fitting attribute instead of arn

Comment: @MarkoE this did not work. Even completely removing event_bus_name throws the same error. I feel that the issue is with the JSON, but I don't see how or why.

Comment: Which provider version are you using?

Comment: 3.0 for aws, 0.34 for auth0

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly 3.0? Because this issue should have been fixed in versions >= 3.39.0.

Comment: Using 4.36.1 throws the same error...

Comment: @dantevn5 did you ever find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.